# Why Chrome DeveloperTools shows large source file as a set of numbered parts, instead of a single file?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I recently noticed that my application source file is shown in Chrome Developer Tools as a set of numbered chunks instead of a single file (as it is returned by web-server). https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PnA2.png.

Want to know why it is happening and how disable this behavior. I find it pretty confusing. Sometimes I want to see a complete file, to search in it, put breakpoints, but I do not know what part contains the piece of code I'm interested in.

The file is pretty huge and I guess Chrome internally splits it because of the size.